# Unit test function that relies on an MySQL connection in JEST es6

Tags: mysql, node.js, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have an NodeJS application, the application is based on NodeJS es6 and is intend to be used as a large module in future projects. Thus i want to properly test as much as possible. I have some experience with Jest so Im trying to use this.

On of the files makes a mysql pool with this code lets call the file DBCon.js

```
export default function getPool () {
  if (!pool) {
    console.log('connecting to Mysql')
    pool = mysql.createPool(dbConfig)
  }
  return pool
}
```

Another file, api.js uses the pool to fire a query and get a project list like so

```
import DBConnector from './DBCon.js'

export function getProjectlist (callback) {
  DBConnector().query(projectList, (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) {
      callback(new ApiError('fetch project failed', 10), 0)
    } else {
      callback(null, results)
    }
  })
}
```

I want to test this code with the following unit test

```
 it('query succeeds', () => {
    DBConnector().query.mockImplementation((query, callback) => {
      callback(null, 'mocked-results')
    })

    const callback = jest.fn()
    getProjectlist(callback)

    const mockedResults = 'test'
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null, mockedResults)
  })
```

When I do this Im getting the following error

`DBConnector(...).query.mockImplementation is not a function`

I tried rewriting the DBConnector to a different structure but it didnt work.

I tried mocking the DBConnector function but it didnt work.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: missing function call parenthesis on .query? maybe it should be `DBConnector(...).query().mockImplementation(...` ?

Comment: With or without parenthesis the issue remains unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You didn't mock the `DBCon.js` module correctly
- You need to call `done()` function when testing the [asynchronous code](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks)
- You may want to define the `projectList`  parameter for `getProjectlist` function.

e.g.

`DBCon.js`:

```js
let pool;
export default function getPool() {
    if (!pool) {
        console.log('connecting to Mysql');
        pool = mysql.createPool(dbConfig);
    }
    return pool;
}
```

`api.js`:

```js
import DBConnector from './DBCon.js';

export function getProjectlist(projectList, callback) {
    DBConnector().query(projectList, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            callback(new ApiError('fetch project failed', 10), 0);
        } else {
            callback(null, results);
        }
    });
}
```

`api.test.js`:

```js
import { getProjectlist } from './api';
import DBConnector from './DBCon';

jest.mock('./DBCon');

it('query succeeds', (done) => {
    const pool = {
        query: (query, callback) => {
            callback(null, 'mocked-results');
        },
    };
    DBConnector.mockImplementation(() => pool);

    const callback = (error, data) => {
        expect(error).toBeNull();
        expect(data).toBe('mocked-results');
        done();
    };
    getProjectlist('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', callback);
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/77015029/api.test.js (5.726 s)
  ✓ query succeeds (2 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   54.55 |       25 |   66.67 |   54.55 |                   
 DBCon.js |      20 |        0 |       0 |      20 | 3-7               
 api.js   |   83.33 |       50 |     100 |   83.33 | 6                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.958 s, estimated 6 s
```

package versions:

```json
"mysql": "^2.18.1",
```